# CSS, HTML On Active Parent/Children

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set my panel/block to a different color when it has been clicked e.g. active.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content nobg">
        <div class="sideEffectBox text-center medium-6 columns">
            <div class="panel hlib"> <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/Icon_Transparent_Loupe_256x256.png"/>

 <span class="linkText">Record Side Effects</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS is:

```
.container .content .panel.hlib {
    background: #ECC100;
    border:none;
    text-align:center;
}

.sideEffectBox :active{
    background: pink;
}
.container .content .panel.hlib :active {
    background: pink;
    border:10px black solid;
}
.container .content .panel.hlib img {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
    height: 110px;
}
.container .content .panel.hlib .linkText {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #605748;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I have a JS fiddle located here: http://jsfiddle.net/liammccann1992/hSu4c/300/

The problem I am having is it's only setting the thing I click to active e.g. the text or the image but shouldn't there parent be active to?

Is there anyway I can force the parent to be active and not them?

Comment: you should remove the space before :active, so it becomes .hlib:active instead of .hlib :active

Comment: You can't target parent by child on css. This ll be available on css 4.

Comment: @WesselvanderLinden can you make that an answer so I can accept that works perfect. I am such a dummy! JS Fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/liammccann1992/gkqs5eed/

Comment: done, nice that it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as said in my comment, remove the space before `:active` and it should be solved :)

Comment: Any idea why :active is triggerd on android when it's a fast tap?